# Photos not showing, have exclamation mark, videos won't play

Tags: storage, photos, video

I recently ran out of space so added a MicroSD card and moved photos and videos on the phone to it, and changed settings so photos and videos always go to the SD card.

Since then, or around that time, when viewing photos in the gallery, the old photos show up okay, but newer photos are blank with an exclamation mark and open as blank photos. Videos show the same but come up with a message about possibly not supporting the type of video file (mp4).

Auto upload to Onedrive is enabled and the photos can be viewed there okay, but videos will not play.

(Microsofy Lumia 550, Windows 10)

Comment: Which Lumia that you're having? and did you try to do a soft reset (hold volume down + power key until vibrate and restart)? Are you able to view the photos/videos if you save directly to the phone memory instead of memory card?

Comment: It's a Lumia 550. I will try switching back to phone memory and let you know if it works.

Comment: After doing a (hard) reset, my new photo's were simply... gone.